# Do hidden input fields have to be escaped in ColdFusion?

Tags: input, coldfusion, hidden, html-escape-characters

Using ColdFusion 8 I usually escape all my form inputs like so:

```
<input id="foo" value="#XMLFormat(trim( form_name.param_name ))#" />
```

So how about hidden inputs? Should these also be escaped? I haven't tried, but I could very well pull a hidden input up in Firebug, enter whatever and try to submit, can I?

Comment: You basically give the answer yourself with your Firebug example... :)

Comment: Thanks! Make it an answer, so I can check

Comment: Yes, even if they're hidden fields, any HTML metachars in the field name can "break" your page.

Comment: <cfloop index="Language" list="HTML,XML,JS,CSS,etc,etc,etc">
If you're outputting a variable **anywhere** within #Language#, it needs to be appropriately encoded to prevent #Language# injection.
</cfloop>

Comment: @PeterBoughton. Thx. Last question: what if my input type="hidden" value="foo"? Do I value="#XMLFormat(trim( foo ))#"? Just in case someone replaces "foo" with whatever?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What a client might do to HTML is not relevant to how the HTML text is originally generated on the server.

Comment: Your `value="foo"` is a static value, _not_ a variable. If you are (on a subsequent request) outputting `value="#form.foo#"` instead then you are dealing with a variable (and thus need to encode it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of escaping in this case is to keep the HTML well formed so yes - hidden vars need to be escaped (or encoded) as well. I usually use urlencodedformat() for this. Consider what would happen if the value you were placing in the hidden var were a variable like this:

```
<cfset form.fullname= 'Bob "the tiger" Johnson'/>

<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="#form.fullname#"/>
```

The output would actually look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="Bob "the Tiger" Johnson"/>
```

This would mean your hidden var would come through as "Bob " ... and the rest would be lost. The situation might get worse if any part of your strings contain HTML or slashes or angle brackets.

Comment: So what if my hidden input has a value="no", what's the syntax to escape set values?

Comment: you can bracket it with urlencodedformat() or htmleeditformat() (or xmlformat() would probably work as well) - but it would have no impact - nothing would be "Escaped" because "no" has no html or edit problems with it.